# Twig foreach that wraps each result in groups of 4 inside a div wrapper

Tags: symfony, twig, haml

In Twig I require that each group of four results is wrapped inside a div.

This is the final html I want, each group of 4 items must be wrapped:

```
{% for item in items %}
<div class="wrapper">
  {{ item }}
  {{ item }}
  {{ item }}
  {{ item }}
</div>
<div class="wrapper">
  {{ item }}
  {{ item }}
  {{ item }}
  {{ item }}
</div>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: I see you have an accepted answer, but also check out [`batch`](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/filters/batch.html) that seems quite similar to `each_slice`.

Comment: @Maerlyn, great contribution!. Please put it as comment with code, and I'll give you a vote. Your answer deserves more attention.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you're using twig => 1.14.2, you can use [divisible by](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/tests/divisibleby.html)

```
{% for item in items %}
  {% if loop.index0 is divisible by(4) %}
    <div class="wrapper">
  {% endif %}
    {{ item }}
  {% if loop.index is divisibleby(4) or loop.last %}
    </div>  
  {% endif %}  
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 9):

Twig has a filter called [`batch`](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/filters/batch.html) that seems to do what `each_slice` does. In your case, here's what the code would look like:

```
{% for row in items|batch(4) %}
    <div class="wrapper">
    {% for item in row %}
        {{ item }}
    {% endfor %}
    </div>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Much cleaner solution and simplifies the logic - lose those ugly if statements from the marked solution!

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
{% for item in items %}
{% if loop.index0 % 4 == 0 %}<div class="wrapper">{% endif %}
  {{ item }}
{% if loop.index % 4 == 0 %}</div>{% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: The answer by @devilcius is worth noting for its final div accomplished by `...or loop.last`